# Font size problem in google chrome?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, fonts

The font size on many websites while using google chrome is so small whereas it looks fine in firefox. How can i fix this problem?

Even on my windows xp computer font looks normal but google chrome on ubuntu definitely has some problem with fonts.

Answer (score 1):

While on a web page, hold down Ctrl key, move mouse wheel, you will see font change size.  Let us know if this works for you.